# how to configure username when creating parallels ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, parallels, username

parallels desktop creates a username called 'parallels' instead of letting you choose. Is there a way to configure it?
(to avoid going through https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username)

EDIT: this seems possible only when creating a VM from a downloadable iso, not from the built in options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're starting from scratch, it's easier and cleaner to just add a new administrator user and delete the default `parallels` user. If you use the GUI's System Settings > User Account, it's extremely easy.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-add.html

Comment: Should be marked as an answer @timotheecour